# Subtracting Two Strings in R

Tags: r, string

I have this data in R:

```
string_1 = c("newyork 123", "california 123", "washington 123")
string_2 = c("123 red", "123 blue", "123 green")
my_data = data.frame(string_1, string_2)
```

I want to "subtract" `string_2` from `string_1`. The result would look something like this:

```
"newyork", "california", "washington"
```

I tried to do this:

```
library(tidyverse)

# did not work as planned
> str_remove(string_1, "string_2")

[1] "newyork 123"    "california 123" "washington 123"
```

But this is not performing a "full" subtraction.

- Does anyone know how to do this?
- Should I try to do this with an ANTI JOIN in SQL?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to define what "subtracting" a string actually means here.  Given an input of `newyork 123` and output `newyork`, what happens to the `red` substring in `123 red` ?

Answer (score 5):

You could split both strings and find the set difference of them.

```r
mapply(setdiff, strsplit(string_1, "\\s+"), strsplit(string_2, "\\s+"))

# [1] "newyork"    "california" "washington"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(purrr)

list1 <- str_split(string_1, pattern = " ")
list2 <- str_split(string_2, pattern = " ")

a <- map2(list1, list2, function(x, y){
    
    output <- setdiff(x, y)
    return(output)
  }) %>% unlist()
```

Comment: In `map2()`, `unlist(x) %>% as.vector()` is redundant. Just `output <- setdiff(x, y)`.

Comment: So your code can be simplified to `map2_chr(list1, list2, function(x, y) setdiff(x, y))` and even to `map2_chr(list1, list2, ~ setdiff(.x, .y))` and even to `map2_chr(list1, list2, setdiff)`. Note that `map2_chr()` can save you the use of the last `unlist()`.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

string_1 <- c("newyork 123", "california 123", "washington 123")
string_2 <- c("123 red", "123 blue", "123 green")

my_data <- data.frame(string_1, string_2)

my_data %>%
    mutate(
        subtracted = map2(
            str_split(string_1, "\\s+"),
            str_split(string_2, "\\s+"),
            ~ setdiff(.x, .y)
        ) %>% map_chr(~ paste0(.x, collapse = " "))
    )

#>         string_1  string_2 subtracted
#> 1    newyork 123   123 red    newyork
#> 2 california 123  123 blue california
#> 3 washington 123 123 green washington
```

If I change the string_2 as @DarrenTsai suggested, we also get what we intended to get

```r
string_1 <- c("newyork 123", "california 123", "washington 123")
string_2_test <- c("123 red", "456 blue", "789 green")

my_data <- data.frame(string_1, string_2_test)

my_data %>%
    mutate(
        subtracted = map2(
            str_split(string_1, "\\s+"),
            str_split(string_2_test, "\\s+"),
            ~ setdiff(.x, .y)
        ) %>% map_chr(~ paste0(.x, collapse = " "))
    )

#>         string_1 string_2_test     subtracted
#> 1    newyork 123       123 red        newyork
#> 2 california 123      456 blue california 123
#> 3 washington 123     789 green washington 123
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Replace `string_2` with `string_2 <- c("123 red", "456 blue", "789 green")` and use your code again. The "123" in the 2nd and 3rd `string_1` should not be removed but you delete them, right? That's because `unlist()` melts all sub-strings together, but `setdiff()` should be done "pairwisely".

Comment: Oh, I see, this solution is then incomplete. I need to do better then, Thanks @DarrenTsai

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gsub` + `mapply` + `trimws` to achieve it

```
> trimws(mapply(function(x, y) gsub(x, "", y), gsub("\\s+", "|", string_2), string_1))
     123|red     123|blue    123|green
   "newyork" "california" "washington"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `tidyverse`, where you split the `string_2` for each row, then collapse into a string that we can use to search for any of the words (i.e., using `|` as "or"; so e.g., "123" or "red", etc.), then remove those using `str_remove_all`. Then, we can `pull` the `string_1` column with the deletions.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(string_1 = trimws(str_remove_all(string_1, str_c(
    unlist(str_split(string_2, " ")), collapse = "|")))) %>%
  pull(string_1)
```

**Output**

```
[1] "newyork"    "california" "washington"
```